# Solve a coupled second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a mechanics problem, I am trying to solve for the motion of two particles with position vectors $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{r_2}$.

I have written the equation's of motion in the form
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} \ddot{\boldsymbol{r_1}} \\ \ddot{\boldsymbol{r_2}} \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} \boldsymbol{r_1} \\ \boldsymbol{r_2} \end{array} \right)$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are constants.

As the problem suggests, I have found the two real eigenvalues, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, and eigenvectors, $\boldsymbol{u_1}, \boldsymbol{u_2}$, corresponding to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. The problem then says to use these to solve for $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{r_2}$, but I don't know where to go from here. How do I solve a system of this form?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r(t)=e^{\lambda t}\mathbf{u}$. Then one has
$$ \lambda^2e^{\lambda t}\mathbf{u}=A e^{\lambda t}\mathbf{u}\text{ or }A\mathbf{u}=\lambda^2\mathbf{u} $$
where
$$ A=\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right). $$
Thus $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be two eigenvalues of $A$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\mathbf{u_1,u_2}$. Then
$$ \lambda_1^2=\mu_1,\lambda_2=\mu_2^2, A\mathbf{u}_1=\lambda_1^2\mathbf{u}_1, A\mathbf{u}_2=\lambda_2^2\mathbf{u}_2$$ Then the general solution $\mathbf{r}(t)$ can be expressed as
$$ \mathbf{r}(t)=(c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda_1}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda_1}t})\mathbf{u}_1+(c_3e^{\sqrt{\lambda_2}t}+c_4e^{-\sqrt{\lambda_2}t})\mathbf{u}_2.$$
Here $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$ is assumed. If $\mu_1=\mu_2$, you can treat similarly.

Comment: Am I right in saying that your $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ is my $\left( \begin{array}{c} \boldsymbol{r_1} \\ \boldsymbol{r_2} \end{array} \right)$? If so, then how do I get a solution for $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{r_2}$? Since equating components would mean that $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{r_2}$ become scalars.